# Why is rails html_safe method changing my html structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm passing a self-closing anchor tag with no text value, just a name:

```
<% test = '<h4><a name="139-01"/>test</h4>' %>
```

When I output the value it looks like this:

```
<h4><a name="139-01"/>test</h4>
```

Then I try to use .html_safe to output it as an html tag

```
<%= test.html_safe %>
```

The resulting code is:

```
<h4><a name="139-01">test</a></h4>
```

As you can see above the anchor tag was change from a self-closing tag to a tag that includes the text "test" for some reason. Does anyone know why this is occurring?

If I set the string to:

```
<% test = '<h4><a name="139-01"></a>test</h4>' %>
```

It works as expected:

```
<h4><a name="139-01"></a>test</h4>
```

The problem is that I don't have access to change the tag in the actual data.

Comment: Did you double-check by looking at the HTML source code of the page that Ruby actually added the closing `</a>`? I would argue that a [self-closing hyperlink tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Properties) is invalid HTML and therefore guess that the browser just tries its best to understand this invalid html and adds the closing `</a>` tag where it thinks it makes sense.

Comment: I found a way to change the input data that resolved the issue but I'd still like to understand why .html_safe changes the markup.

Comment: This question seems to suggset self-closing tags are invalid in HTML5 "HTML5 basically behaves as if the trailing slash is not there. There is no such thing as a self-closing tag in HTML5 syntax."  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5

Comment: @spickermann I think your answer is correct. It's the browser changing the tag because it's trying to fix the markup. If I put the markup directly in the browser it displays the "wrong" way. If you would like to make an official answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not Ruby on Rails changing your HTML.

A self-closing hyperlink simply is invalid HTML. And it is the browser that tries its best to parse and understand this invalid HTML and the browser adds the closing `</a>` tag where it thinks it makes the most sense.

Relevant in this context:

- The very limited list of [HTML *void elements*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#elements-2) that are can be self-closing.
- And [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)